# How to track long running operaton through reconciler in Kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, operators, kubernetes-operator

I have written a piece of code in k8s operator, this task is taking longer time to complete that blocking my reconciler till completing the task. I want to implement a logic where I will not have to wait till completing the task, instead, I want to get a notification to the reconciler after completing the task.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you've suggested, it is best practice to keep an operator's reconcile process as short-lived as possible to ensure that the operator can quickly reconcile events and communicate updates via the resource's status in a timely manner. The best way to optimize an operator's reconcile method will always be unique to the operator, but I've included a few scenario's that may apply to your operator:

**Scenario 1: When reconciling your CR, your operator needs to create a set of child resources and ensure that they are in some state.**

In this scenario, your best bet is to use [owner labels to requeue the CR](https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/watching-resources/operator-managed.html) as the child resources reach the correct state. Your operator's reconcile method would need to be updated to:

- Create the resources if they do not exist.
- Check that the resources are in the correct state.

**Scenario 2: Your operator needs to perform long running logic when reconciling a resource**

In this scenario, it may make sense to move the long running logic into a [Kubernetes Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) or externally ran process. Your operator controller would then need to requeue the CR once the job finishes, similar to the process described in scenario 1.

It's also possible to configure your operator to reconcile multiple CRs at once, but this won't fix an inherent design issue in your reconcile method.

Hopefully that helps, if the scenarios above don't apply, please reach out with additional details.